# Integration of cloudant with django

Tags: django, cloudant

I am new to cloudantdb and django. Is there any way to integrate cloudantdb with danjgo framework. Is it possible to connect cloudant with django?

Answer (score 2):

As you may be aware, Cloudant is built on Apache CouchDB, so if you can't find references for Cloudant, it's usually worth also searching for CouchDB. I don't really use Django, but a quick search throws up the following references:

- http://leok.me/2013/05/02/what-you-need-to-know-couchdb-django/
- https://lethain.com/an-introduction-to-using-couchdb-with-django/
- http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/11/10/using-couchdb-django/
- https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/couchdb/

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all solutions on the web are very outdated.

The solution used by IBM in a capstone project on Coursera was:

1. Use *SQLite* backend in your Django app
2. Create *Cloud Functions* for communicating with *Cloudant*
3. Create REST API definitions in your Django app that utilize the *Cloud Functions* to communicate with *Cloudant*

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works. I do feel like *SQLite* is redundant at this point but without it, I couldn't get the app to work.